# Hibernate - Create UserInfo entry automatically when a new User is added

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I use Hibernate for my postgres database and I need it to create a new line into the "User_Info" table each time a new User is added.

I have two entities :

**User**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private UserInfoEntity infos;
}
```

**UserInfo**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="user_info")
public class UserInfoEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "user_id", referencedColumnName  = "id")
    private UserEntity user;
}
```

So here I am creating a OneToOne relationship between the two entities.
The Id of UserInfoEntity should be the same as the UserEntity.

I don't really understand why it won't work as I've set cascade to CascadeType.ALL in UserEntity. But as you could imagine no lines are inserted when I create a new user.

I really want this relationship, and I really want them to both share the same Id as they are deeply linked together.

I tried to put a constructor in UserEntity like that :

```java
public User(){
    this.infos = new UserInfoEntity();
}
```

But it had no effect.

I use a simple Controller using Quarkus to persist the data

```java
    @POST
    @ReactiveTransactional
    public Uni<Response> createUser(UserEntity user) {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("user was invalidly set on request.", 422);
        }
        LOGGER.info("creating user: " + user.getName());
        return service.persist(user)
                .map(persistedUser -> Response
                        .created(URI.create("/users/" + user.id))
                        .entity(persistedUser)
                        .build())
                .onFailure().recoverWithItem(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build());
    }
```

I don't want to create the entry "manually" each times as I am pretty sure it is possible to do it with annotations like that.

What could I do so that each time a new User is inserted, a UserInfo is also created ?
I also want OrphanRemoval so no UserInfo should remain if the User is not in the database anymore.

I'm pretty new to Hibernate so let me know if there's anything weird in my code and what would be more appropriate in my case.

Thank you.

Comment: You should show the code that creates and persists the 2 entities for a new user.

Comment: You are doing a parent-child relationship but you're missing to set `UserInfoEntity#user` value to relate the entities

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `UserEntity#userInfos` is not null when you call `service.persist()`? Also, did you make sure that `UserInfoEntity#user` points back to the `UserEntity`?

I don't know how your real data model looks like, but you can split an entity into two tables as well if you want, by using `@SecondaryTable`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@SecondaryTable(name = "user_info"
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Column(table = "user_info")
    private String moreInfo;
}
```